# How to make an object "fly" towards the mouse XNA

Tags: c#, xna, trigonometry, game-physics

I am trying to make an object glide towards the mouse every time it is clicked. It will constantly be moving. Right now, if I click in front of it (above or below) it moves in the general direction, but at the wrong angle. When I click behind it, it will just slow down a lot, and the closest it gets is moving very slowly.

```
if (isdown()) //if the mouse is clicked
{
    double paulx = Paullocation.X + radius; //midpoints of object
    double pauly = Paullocation.Y + radius;
    double targetx = ms.X; //clicked location
    double targety = ms.Y;
    if (isdown(Keys.Space)) //if space is pressed
    {
        double hypotenuse = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(paulx - targetx, 2) + Math.Pow(pauly - targety, 2));
        //finds hypotenuse^
        double xcomponent = targetx - paulx; //finds both legs of triangle
        double ycomponent = targety - pauly; //that is made by mouse

        Paulincrement.X = (float)Math.Cos(xcomponent / hypotenuse); //main issue
        Paulincrement.Y = (float)Math.Sin(ycomponent / hypotenuse); //main issue

    }
}
Paullocation.X += Paulincrement.X;
Paullocation.Y += Paulincrement.Y;
```

Comment: Why are you using cos/sin? They don't make sense in this context to me.

Comment: I need to find the angle of the imaginary triangle created from the mouse and the position of the object to figure out how much "x" and how much "y" to add.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `Paullocation` is a `Vector2` you can simply compute the difference between its position and the coordinate you've clicked with the mouse, then normalizing it you will get the direction to follow.

```
Vector2 direction = new Vector2(mouse.X, mouse.Y) - Paullocation;
direction.Normalize();

Paullocation += direction * speed;
```

Comment: The `Vector2` structure and its methods can be very useful, you should take a look :)

Comment: How would I alter this so that once it hits the mouse, it will bounce off in the same angle (if its going northeast 30 degrees, it hits the mouse and bounces down southeast 30 degrees)?

Comment: Just multiply `direction` by `-1`, but I think you will need to declare that variable as class variable.